# Typehint Union Dictionary branching error

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting

I want to implement a function like the one below, but it throws a type hint warning.

```py
def test(flag: bool)->Dict[str, int]| Dict[str, str]:
    a: Dict[str, str]| Dict[str, int] = {}
    if flag:
        a['a'] = 1
    else:
        a['a'] = 'hello'
    return post_process(a)
```

[image]

With the following warning by Pylance:

```py
Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__value" of type "str" in function "__setitem__"
  "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

I know the following is a solution, but it is not very semantically pleasing.
Since semantically, a and b are the same, but it appears to be different.

```py
def test()->Dict[str,int]|Dict[str, str]:
    flag = True
    if flag:
        a: Dict[str, int] = {'a': 1}
        return a
    else:
        b: Dict[str, str] = {'a': 'hello'}
        return b
    if flag:
        return post_process(a)
    else:
        return post_process(b)
```

Is there a solution that looks like the code below, that does not throw type hint warnings?:

```py
def test(flag: bool)->Dict[str, int]| Dict[str, str]:
    a: Dict[str, str]| Dict[str, int] = {}
    if flag:
        a: Dict[str, str]
        a['a'] = 1
    else:
        a: Dict[str, int]
        a['a'] = 'hello'
    return post_process(a)
```

Note that if a weren't a dictionary and a literal type it could work:

```py
def test(flag: bool)-> int|str:
    a: int| str
    if flag:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 'hello'
    return post_process(a)
```

I want an implementation that do not contradict with the type hint system, without sacrificing any of the readability of the actual code. Thank you.

I know type hint warnings are not a part of the python protocol, but I am using Pylance linting system.

Comment: "but it throws a type hint warning" Which warning? The screenshot only shows a red wriggly line, which can be any IDE warning.

Comment: Nowhere in your post did you show, what the actual error is, aside from that screenshot with a squiggly line. EDIT: @MisterMiyagi haha, literally seconds apart...

Comment: I'm not sure the code as shown is sensible (and thus it is hard to say how else to do it). From a typing standpoint, `flag` has no relation at all to the type of `a` – you might well leave out `flag` plus the `if`/`else` and it would be the same for typing. In the end you are assigning an `int` to something you have explicitly said may not be an `int`.

Comment: The reason why I did not post it is because, different linter will show different errors but for pylance it gave: "Literal[1]" is incompatible with "str". I have updated the post with more info.

Comment: I have used an if to demonstrate that the program needs to refer to the same variable after some branching logic. But assigns a different type to the variable in each branch [scope].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:
Since your comment outlined that you truly want the return value to be only ever a dict of strings or a dict of ints, and never a mix of both, you can use the `@overload` decorator to determine return types based on the boolean flag:

```py
from typing import Dict, overload, Literal


@overload
def test(flag: Literal[True]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    ...


@overload
def test(flag: Literal[False]) -> Dict[str, str]:
    ...


def test(flag):
    a = {}
    if flag:
        a["a"] = 1
    else:
        a["a"] = "hello"
    return a


b = test(True)  # Intellisensed as Dict[str, int]

c = test(False)  # Intellisensed as Dict[str, str]
```

**Original Post**:

I was able to recreate your error and resolve it with `Dict[str, str | int]` like so:

```py
def test(flag: bool)->Dict[str, int | str]:
    a: Dict[str, int | str] = {}
    if flag:
        a['a'] = 1
    else:
        a['a'] = 'hello'
    return a
```

Notice that if you swap the order of the `int` and `str` in `a: Dict[str, int | str] = {}`, then either assignment of `a['a']` will fail. This helps indicate that your type hint suggests that the return value is either ONLY a dict of strings, or ONLY a dict of ints, but when intellisense reads your code, it sees that there's a possibility of a variable dict type, that of strings AND integers. If you wanted to type the return to be either a dict ONLY containing strings based on a flag, or ONLY containing integers based on the same flag, then check out the `@overload` decorator from the typing library.

Comment: I thought you might be looking for that! I'll update the answer with the @overloads example I alluded to. Hold tight

Comment: Thank you very much for the amazing work!

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to type hint the local variable inside the function as well? I guess at this point, they could be given different names but.

Comment: Can you please not use images from the IDE? They are very hard to read and hardly represent the relevant IDE output; especially the red underline is next to useless. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sure thing @MisterMiyagi, I'll remove them and comment the intended value

Comment: I personally found images from IDE a fine resource for communicating this. Since it gave me ideas on where type hint through warnings. 
Especially in this context, where the implementations of warnings would differ depending on the editor you are using.

Comment: @WantingtobeanAndroidDevelor That is an unreasonable position to say the least. If you encounter an error from _any_ static type checker, that is either an actual error in your code, in which case it doesn't matter what the _exact_ error message is because it will explain what is wrong either way _or_ it is caused by a bug in the type checker itself, in which case the specific error message is relevant to be able to reproduce and/or report the bug. Instead all you present is "there is something wrong here, you go figure out what it is".